# If I pull every 1 minute with a script on my linux server from Github, will I be banned?

Tags: linux, github, repo

I have two repos on Gitee and Github, and I want to use my personal server on linux to sync them. What I've done is to pull every 1 minute from github and then push to Gitee. Will I suffer from ban for doing this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a question about an external parties legalities rather than a programming problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not receiving updates on your public repo at this frequency, you could also consider setting up an `on: push` actions workflow to sync the changes only as they happen. It would probably make GitHub happier than a script that polls for changes when it's not needed. You could use a locally hosted GitHub runner to push the changes into your local git server's repo.